# Android : Intent or Handler + listener + runnable?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-intent, handler, runnable

My app is parsing data from an inputStream in a background thread. It must push 
messages to the gui depending on the read data.

Few months ago I did an implentation that runs something like this :

- The activiy implements a specific listener interface (one method per message type, the message parameters are passed as a structured parameter of the method).
- The activity registers the listener somewhere.
- each time the reading thread has something to push to the activity, it creates
  a runnable that is pushed to a handler (created in gui thread). The runnable 
  is executed in the activity thread and calls the listener's method.

That's works pretty smoothly but...

Some days ago while reading a book, I discovered intents. Itents may replace
this structure by a simple intent broadcast with activity registering on needed
intents.

Today, I wonder which solution would fit the best in terms of performance.
Of course the first solution is more complex in terms of number of classes but 
that does not presume of the performance...

Anybody has any clue ?

Thanks

Julien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder which solution would fit the best in terms of performance

That depends on what you mean by "a simple intent broadcast".

If you mean that you are calling `sendBroadcast()` and `registerReceiver()` on your `Activity` or other `Context`, this will be worse in performance, as this involves inter-process communication (IPC), even if the broadcaster and the receiver are in the same process. It also raises security issues, as any app on the system could send you those broadcasts.

If you mean that you are calling `sendBroadcast()` and `registerReceiver()` on a singleton instance of `LocalBroadcastManager`, that is fine, and should be comparable speed-wise to what you were using. `LocalBroadcastManager` implements an in-process event bus, eliminating the overhead and security issues of system-level broadcasts.

Personally, I would use another event bus implementation, like [greenrobot's EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), for ease of programming.

Comment: I was planning to use LocalBroadcastManager. Greenrobot's EventBus is interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should know that if using broadcasts, you will receive the result a noticeable time later (say delay)

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: @Saket no, I did some research a while ago for which is better. Broadcast is better and easier to avoid leaks if you have several listeners, but if you have a single interface, I have seen that it is much faster to use an interface rather then broadcast.